# Styled-components - Override part of theme

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using `styled-components` to handle my styling in a react app.

Using the `ThemeProvider` wrapper, I'm able to get access to my theme in all of my styled components

However, i was wondering if it was possible to override just a part of the theme.

Here's a quick example:

Let's say I got the following theme:

```
const theme = {
    color: 'red';
    backgroundColor: 'blue';
}
```

I pass it to my app:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <MyStyledComponent>
      <p>Hi</p>
   <MyStyledComponent>
</ThemeProvider>
```

MyStyledComponent is a styled div which receives my theme:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  ${props => ({
    color: props.theme.color,
    background-color: props.theme.backgroundColor,
  })}
`

export default StyledButton
```

If I display this, I will have a blue div with some red text in it.

Now, if I use the following:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <MyStyledComponent theme={{color: 'green',}}>
      <p>Hi</p>
   <MyStyledComponent>
</ThemeProvider>
```

My text will turn green, BUT, no more blue background-color.

Is there a generic way to make sure that custom themes only override the properties that are found in both theme objects ?

Comment: What is the code of `MyStyledComponent` ?

Comment: @GaëlS I added it in my question

Comment: how about `theme={{...theme, color: 'green' }}` ?

Answer (score 3):

The `theme` used by `MyStyledComponent`gets indeed totally overridden by the closest `ThemeProvider` defined.

Previous solution works well but to avoid to duplicate everywhere `{{...theme.color, color: 'green'}}` for instance, one can create a small wrapper:

```
const WithMainTheme = ({ theme: localTheme, children, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={{ ...theme, ...localTheme }}>
      {React.cloneElement(children, props)}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

which will allow you to write :

```
  <WithMainTheme theme={{ color: "green" }}>
      <MyStyledComponent>Hi</MyStyledComponent>
    </WithMainTheme>
```

to get your button with `color: green`

See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-kirch-lxro5) for a running example

Answer (score 1):

you can just do like normal Object in JS using spread operator and overriding the ones you want at the end.

```
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <MyStyledComponent theme={{...theme,color: 'green'}}>
      <p>Hi</p>
   <MyStyledComponent>
</ThemeProvider>
```